# google maps popup info box when clicking marker

Tags: google-maps, popup, infobox

I'm using this google map script. How would I do if I want an info box to popup when I click the marker?

You can try the script here: http://clark-kim.se/preview/googlemaps2.html

I was not able to post all the code but here's the script at least:

```
<script>
          function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            });
            var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
                new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
            map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

            var input = document.getElementById('target');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            var markers = [];

            google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
              var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

              for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                marker.setMap(null);
              }

              markers = [];
              var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
              for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
                var image = {
                  url: place.icon,
                  size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  icon: image,
                  title: place.name,
                  position: place.geometry.location
                });

                markers.push(marker);

                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
              }

              map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
              var bounds = map.getBounds();
              searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
            });
          }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help? If yes please check one so this topic can be considered closed, if not please provide some feedback or an answer of your own

Answer (score 0):

```
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent("Your content here");
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
```

You have to create an infowindow first and then on every click you close it on one end and open it on the other

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked this [example?](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) of Google Maps JavaScript API v3